# ReferenceError: "google" is not defined for Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-sites

I want my page to display a chart in google site, the datasource i used is google spreadsheet. I test my code and it works well in JSFiddle. But when i copy my code to Google Apps Script, it fail with ReferenceError: "google" is not defined. I have no idea about it, I don't know what should be added ot use google.visualization API, maybe Google Apps Script doesn't support google.visualization API? I just add function doGet(), You can see my code:

```
 function doGet() {
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
                 var query = new google.visualization.Query(
                 'https://docs.google.com/a/valeo.com/spreadsheets/d/1wMku94s8LsbwPdoaVsJNL5IPdKVUdv8ZC_jgo2suV4Q/edit#gid=1287756093');
                 query.setQuery('select A, C');
                 query.send(handleQueryResponse);
        }

        function handleQueryResponse(response) {
            if (response.isError()) {
              alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
              return;
            }
            var data = response.getDataTable();
            var options = {
                           title: 'MS Project Licence From 2014',
                           hAxis: {title: 'Month',titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
                          };
            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
  }
```

Appreciated for any suggestion

Comment: Show us the jsFiddle.

Comment: You can use Charts Service.  [Documentation Link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/)

Comment: JavaScript in typically run client side from your browser.  Apps Script also uses JavaScript for server side code; the .gs script file.  Running JavaScript from a `<script>` tag in HTML, and running it from a .gs file in Apps Script is different.  The Quick Start documentation shows a script tag that loads a Google jsAPI  `<!--Load the AJAX API--><script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>`  That makes the  `Google` library available.  [Loading the Library](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs)

Comment: Yes, I've put `<script type="text/javascript" src="google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{'name':'visualization','‌​version':'1','packages':['corechart']}]}"></script>` in my main.htlm, and in Code.gs file I call my html file using `return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('main')` but it displays nothing

Comment: Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hh0L7ckn/)